# Removing Qpixmap from QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I enconutered a problem, when dealing with QGraphicsScene and QPixmap. 
I am sequentially displaying frames, captured by the camera. QTimer object is calling updateSingleView() function every 100ms. That is my inner function:

```
void CCIGui::updateSingleView()
{

    unsigned char *const img = PGRSystem->SnapShot();

    QImage Img(img, 1024, 768, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    scenes.at(0)->removeItem(scenes.at(0)->items().at(0));
    scenes.at(0)->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Img));

    ui_camViews.at(0).graphicsView->setScene(scenes.at(0));

    delete [] img;
}
```

Gui is displaying the camera's view but unfortunatelly there is a memory leak, when calling `scenes.at(0)->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Img));` I thought that `removeItem` function should destroy the old QPixmap, but apparently its not. Do you know why the leak occurs and how to solve it?

Comment: What version of Qt? I had some trouble with 4.6.? on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested

you need to delete the item after removeItem line.

i.e

QPointer _item = scenes.at(0)->items().at(0);
scenes.at(0)->removeItem( _item );
delete _item;

scenes.at(0)->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Img));

.....

Answer (score 2):

From the Qt documentation:

> void QGraphicsScene::removeItem ( QGraphicsItem * item )
>
> Removes the item item and all its children from the scene. The ownership of item is passed on to the caller (i.e., QGraphicsScene will no longer delete item when destroyed).
>
> See also addItem().

Hence you need to delete the item using `delete` manually.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem

Comment: Could you be more precise? I can't delete Item using 'delete', as it was not created with 'new' (same for a Pixmap).

Comment: addPixamp(), and the similar helpers on QGraphicsScene, are simple wrappers that create (via new) a QGraphicsItem for you - in this case, a QGraphicsPixmapItem. Hence, you do need to delete this, after the item is remove from the scene.

Comment: Also, returning a char array with your SnapShot() method (which doesn't define ownership) is likely to cause confusion - QByteArray is perfect for this, no delete [] required, and no possible ownership bugs.