# Memory leak using opencv : VideoCapture

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, memory-leaks

I have developed an application with Qt Creator 2.4.1 (Qt 4.8.4) and OpenCV 2.4.2 that reads images from a folder and displays them.

It uses cv::VideoCapture and QGraphicsScene/QGraphicsView. It runs well, however I encounter a memory leak : if I look at the consumed memory in task manager, memory goes up each time a new image is read and end up crashing.

My main window was created with Qt Designer, it's a class that inherits QMainWindow. There is a `QGraphicsView view_src` on it and also a push button : `buttonStart`

Here is a sample of code : Class declaration :

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

namespace Ui {
    class FenetrePrinc;
}

class FenetrePrinc : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FenetrePrinc(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FenetrePrinc();

public slots:
    virtual void start();
    virtual void tick();
    virtual void stop_timer();

private:
    Ui::FenetrePrinc *ui;

    QString filename;
    QGraphicsScene *scene_src;
    QGraphicsItem *img_src;

    VideoCapture sequence;

    Mat src;
};
```

Class definition :

```
FenetrePrinc::FenetrePrinc(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::FenetrePrinc){

    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene_src = new QGraphicsScene();
    timer = new QTimer(this);

    img_src = scene_src->addPixmap(QPixmap("vide.jpg"));
    ui->view_src->setScene(scene_src);

    connect(ui->buttonStart, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(start()));
}

FenetrePrinc::~FenetrePrinc(){
    delete scene_src;
    delete img_src;
    delete ui;
}

void FenetrePrinc::start(){
    if(src.empty())
        sequence.open(filename.toStdString());

    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tick()));
    timer->start(1000/24);   //24 frames per second

    disconnect(ui->buttonStart, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(start()));
    connect(ui->buttonStart, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(stop_timer()));
}

void FenetrePrinc::tick(){
    sequence >> src;

    if(src.empty())
    {
        sequence.release();
        stop_timer();
        return;
    }

    scene_src->removeItem(img_src);
    img_src = scene_src->addPixmap(convert16uc1(src));

    src.release();
}

void FenetrePrinc::stop_timer(){
    timer->stop();
    disconnect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tick()));

    disconnect(ui->buttonStart, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(stop_timer()));
    connect(ui->buttonStart, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(start()));
}
```

I don't understand why does memory usage goes up and up each time an image is read, I do release the image each time it is read, and release sequence once finished. But maybe I missed something ?

**EDIT :** The function `QPixmap convert16uc1(Mat img)` is the cause of the memory leak. I have to use this function because I am working with 16bits grayscale images, which Qt cannot read. I open images and perform image processing with OpenCV and display the images with Qt.

The code of the function is the following :

```
QPixmap FenetrePrinc::convert16uc1(const cv::Mat& source)
{
  quint16* pSource = (quint16*) source.data;
  int pixelCounts = source.cols * source.rows;

  QImage dest(source.cols, source.rows, QImage::Format_RGB32);

  char* pDest = (char*) dest.bits();

  for (int i = 0; i < pixelCounts; i++)
  {
    quint8 value = (quint8) ((*(pSource)) >> 8);
    *(pDest++) = value;  // B
    *(pDest++) = value;  // G
    *(pDest++) = value;  // R
    *(pDest++) = 0;      // Alpha
    pSource++;
  }
  return QPixmap::fromImage(dest);
}
```

Comment: please try with a more recent opencv version, 2.4.2 is far too old

Comment: if you don't display the images with Qt (just read image and dont display), does it leak memory too?

Comment: @Micka : If I don't display the images, there is no memory leak even if I do not release the image via `src.release();` The line that produces the memory leak is : `img_src = scene_src.addPixmap(convert16uc1(src));`

Comment: @berak : I will try and download a newer version of OpenCV.

Comment: can you post your `convert16uc1` function? Do you have to release Qt pixmap elements?

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612391/qt-memory-leak-using-qpixmap please try a `scene_src->clear()` before `addPixmap`

Comment: @berak: I'm using stoll 2.4.2 very heavily also with Qt. Gigs of images from camera and hard-drive. No memleaks. It is not the OpenCV and of cause not the Qt.

Comment: The function `QPixmap convert16uc1(Mat img)` is the cause of the memory leak.
I have edited my question to add the function code

Comment: does `QPixmap::fromImage(dest);` perform a copy? If not, you either are pointing to freed memory, because `QImage dest` will release memory if going out of scope, or you have a memory leak because you don't free memory of `dest` if QImage doesnt release memory if it goes out of scope.

Comment: After looking at the documentation [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fromImage) it looks like that `QPixmap QPixmap::fromImage(const QImage & image, ...)` does perform a copy.
There is an overloaded version : `QPixmap QPixmap::fromImage(const QImage && image, ...)` that "converts image to pixmap without copying if possible" (qt doc quote).
Unfortunately, I am working with Qt 4.8.4 and the overloaded function was introduced in Qt 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what causes the problem and how to fix it, reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265046/removing-qpixmap-from-qgraphicsscene/4265193#4265193).

From the Qt documentation:

> void QGraphicsScene::removeItem ( QGraphicsItem * item )
>
> Removes the item item and all its children from the scene. The ownership of item is passed on to the caller (i.e., QGraphicsScene will no longer delete item when destroyed).
>
> See also addItem().

Once QGraphicsScene::removeItem(QGraphicsItem *item)` has been called, QGraphicsScene will no longer delete the item whenn destroyed.

Fix : call `delete img_src` after `removeItem(img_src)` : in function `FenetrePrinc::tick()` :

```
void FenetrePrinc::tick(){
    sequence >> src;

    if(src.empty())
    {
        sequence.release();
        stop_timer();
        return;
    }

    scene_src->removeItem(img_src);
    delete img_src;
    img_src = scene_src->addPixmap(convert16uc1(src));

    src.release();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it is `convert16uc1`.

If you can't post convert16uc1 here, try saving the image temporarily in opencv using imwrite and loading the image in Qt. If the the memleak disappears. analyze `convert16uc1`.

Or don't call convert16uc1(src) but call `addPixmap` using some other constant image previously loaded in Qt.

Comment: Yes you are right, if I change `scene_src->addPixmap(convert16uc1(srt))` to `scene_src->addPixmap(QPixmap("vide.jpg"))` I do not have memory leak anymore. I have edited my question to add the `convert16uc1` code.

Comment: I did what you suggested : instead of using `QPixmap convert16uc1(Mat source)` to convert my images from OpenCV to Qt, I used ìmwrite` to save the image temporally, and load this image with Qt.
I do not have memory leak anymore with this technique.

Comment: @zarachbaal: It was only a suggestion for a test! This will be very slow conversion. I'll try out your code and probably find the cause.

Comment: Yes I know this isn't a real solution, I just tried it, it works but this is extremely slow ! I think the cause is `QPixmap::fromImage(dest);` in convert16uc1. There is an overloaded version that converts without copying, but it was implemented in Qt 5.3 and I use Qt 4.8.4.

Comment: @zarachbaal: `fromImage` is hardly a problem. QImage is created on stack. It is deleted when function scope is left.